# Can a Flex App be a Websockets client?

Tags: apache-flex, html, websocket

I don't see why *not!*

Has somebody implemented this so far? Any links?

If not, I will! :-D

Comment: By websockets are you referring to a specific program or technology?  Or do you just mean "sockets" in general?  Support for binary sockets was added in Flash Player 9. And many people use it for bi-directional communication, as long as you have a server side application (such as LiveCycle) that supports server side push.

Comment: By websockets I'm referring to --> http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/websockets/basics/

Comment: Did some quick googling - most things are related to javascript ... i doubt it would take very long to write one with flash.net.socket class... be sure to post it here if you write one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  There is a Socket API that could be a Websockets client.  Also check out [Kaazing](http://www.kaazing.com) - a Websocket server with a Flex client library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. look at GraniteDS, if your backend is in Java. It has everything you need. There is also an example application showing chat using webscoket.